# Error when extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in SecurityConfig

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

When I am extending the WebConfigurerAdapter Class in my WebSecurityConfig of Spring boot Application in IntelliJ, I am getting this error.
I am providing the full stack trace below:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:193) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:153) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:748) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at com.jobopenings.JobPostingsApplication.main(JobPostingsApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:an]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@4d7e1886]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:485) ~[spring-core-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:361) ~[spring-core-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:418) ~[spring-core-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:765) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:764) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:703) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:674) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1684) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:246) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:239) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:229) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:182) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:157) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3434) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2536) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467) ~[spring-core-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
... 36 common frames omitted

2023-07-12 22:54:35.612  WARN 19876 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Unable to close ApplicationContext

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@4d7e1886]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:485) ~[spring-core-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:361) ~[spring-core-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:418) ~[spring-core-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:765) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:764) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:703) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:674) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1684) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:669) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:661) ~[spring-beans-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1302) ~[spring-context-5.3.28.jar:5.3.28]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:864) ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:852) ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:839) ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:779) ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:317) ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at com.jobopenings.JobPostingsApplication.main(JobPostingsApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
... 25 common frames omitted
```

Pom.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.13</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.jobopenings</groupId>
    <artifactId>JobPostings</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>JobPostings</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

WebSecurityConfig -

```
package com.jobopenings.config;

import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }

}
```

I have already tried to remove the scope of

> spring-boot-starter-tomcat

Can anyone please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter` make it seems that there is some conflict in the dependencies. Are you sure that you are not using Spring Boot 3 or Spring Framework 6 somewhere?

Comment: I have downloaded the zip file from start.spring.io using 2.7.13 version

Comment: I do not recall Spring Initializr providing model mapper, lombok, etc.

Comment: I added ModelMapper myself but Lombok was added when I installed the file.

Comment: could you please provide an application somewhere for us to download so that we can have a closer look?